# Should I rewrite Chocolatey's warning messages in my wrapper script?

Tags: powershell, chocolatey

I've bundled a Chocolatey installer into PowerShell: My script calls a function for the installation process. The user is supposed to run `.\install.ps1` in PowerShell. If the package already is installed the output is similar to:

```
<Packagename> already installed.
Use --force to reinstall, specify a version to install, or try upgrade.
```

Ok, so the user should think that `.\install.ps1 --force` will do the trick. Unfortunately, I have found no way for PowerShell to accept double dashes (`--`), so I'm thinking about rewriting the warning message from Chocolatey so it outputs `-force` instead of `--force`:

```
<Packagename> already installed.
Use -force to reinstall, specify a version to install, or try upgrade.
```

My `setup.ps1` file is similar to:

```
Install-App <Packagename + parameters>
```

The function my script is calling is similar to:

```
function Install-App
{
    //..code ommited..
    $chocoCommand = "choco install <Packagename + parameters>"
    iex $chocoCommand
}
```

I've been thinking about try/catch, but haven't figured it out quite yet.

Any suggestions?

Best regards

Comment: _Unfortunately, I have found no way for PowerShell to accept double dashes_  - What have you tried?

Comment: With some further investigation, I found this:

    foreach($arg in $args)
    {
        if($arg -Eq "--force")
        {            
            $forceParameter = "--force"
        }
    }

The question then arises: Is this a good solution? I can easily pass the $forceParameter to my function.

Comment: Do you have multiple arguments to pass?

Comment: Yes, I have multiple arguments to pass.

Comment: If you _expect_ the user to retry, why not apply the `--force` flag in your wrapper by default?

Comment: I want the user to be informed about what happens, and I will not force it by default. I expect the user to _maybe_ retry it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by doing a foreach on $args:

```
foreach($arg in $args)
{
    if($arg -eq "--force" -Or $arg -eq "-force")
    {
        $forceParameter = "--force"
    }
}
```

And further passing this to my PowerShell command

```
MyCustomCommand -forceParameter $forceParameter
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You should try `--%` just before any arguments are passed.

Taken from https://chocolatey.org/docs/commands-reference#how-to-pass-options-switches

Comment: I'm satisfied by foreaching $args and passing the argument further. Thanks for the help!